# OpenLayers Protocol for locally generated geoJSON formatted object

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, geojson

I am generating maps using our local server but the shapes data I'm getting is just arrays.  I'm using JavaScript to convert it to geoJSON but how do I tell OpenLayers to use this obj instead of a URL?  The documentation is flaky and Google isn't providing me the answers.

What I'm currently calling:

```
var marketProtocal = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
   url: 'json/lte_shapes.json',
   format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
});
```

and the container looks similar to:

```
var geoObj = {};

$.getJSON("/shape_server.json", function(result) {
     // convert arrays into new geoJSON obj
     geoObj.push(newGeoJSON);
   }).done(function() {
    // generate map using geoObj
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vectorSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
      loadFeatures();
   },
   strategy:  function(extent, resolution) {
   // some code
    return [extent];
   },
   projection: "EPSG:25832"
});

var localdata ={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name": "EPSG:25832" }},
  "features": [
      { 
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"name": "Hub 1"},
        "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates":  [714844,6178000]}
      }
    ]
  }

var loadFeatures = function() { 
   vectorSource.addFeatures(vectorSource.readFeatures(localdata));
};

var SmallworldLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: vectorSource,
   style: avlFeatureStyle
});
</script>
```

local data is my GeoJson data. use your own.